# Можно как-то вместо кнопки (onclick) программно вызвать public void?

Tags: android

Можно как-то вместо кнопки (onclick) программно вызвать public void?

```
public void coin(View v) {
//код
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `View`, нигде не используется, то просто можете вызвать `coin(null)`. В ином случае вам необходимо найти `View`.

```
public void func(){
   View v = findViewById(R.id.myView);
   coin(v);
}
```

Comment: coin(null);   Cработало для меня Спасибо.